# NodeJS Express - AngularJS - Express handler run twice for one request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a route `router.route('/cart/:_distributor/order').post(handler)`. When I try to send request from AngularJS app to nodejs server, handler function is called once and after 5 seconds again. In Chrome/Firefox dev tools, there is only one request. In Apache (proxy server) access_logs, there is two logs:

```
[12/Jul/2017:10:08:59 +0200] "POST /cart/5739c9fbc19a8b66c2163ebe/order HTTP/1.1" 200 439
[12/Jul/2017:10:09:04 +0200] "POST /cart/5739c9fbc19a8b66c2163ebe/order HTTP/1.1" 200 1253
```

In pm2 logs, same thing:

```
POST /cart/5739c9fbc19a8b66c2163ebe/order 200 5001ms
POST /cart/5739c9fbc19a8b66c2163ebe/order 200 30584ms - 568b
```

Client app must wait about 30s to get response from this request. This problem appears just there, for other requests client-server communication is normal.

```
function handler(req, res, next) {       
    orderModel.createOrder(req.clinic, req.user, req.vc_distributor)
    .then(function(data) {
        res.json(data);
    }, function(err) {
        next(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your handler code in nodejs server

Comment: I added handler code to question

Comment: Could you do simple test to check is . 
Response immediately when the URL was called like this 

`
router.route('/cart/:_distributor/order').post((req, res, next) => {
res.json({})
})
`
check the API was called twice or not

Comment: When I do this, API is called just once, there is just one logs for this
`POST /cart/5739c9fbc19a8b66c2163ebe/order 200 10ms - 2b`

Comment: well, Could you show your code on client side

Comment: Same issue facing.

Comment: On Client side I just send request on click with 
`$http.post('/cart/' + _cart + '/order', body).then((data) => { // showing success message }).catch((err) => {  });`

Comment: Weird... I suggest some ways to check  1) Did your client side and server side is same domain ?  
2) Change your handler code is like this check how many time it was called 

`function handler(req, res, next) {       
    orderModel.createOrder(req.clinic, req.user, req.vc_distributor)
    .then(function(data) {
       console.log('go in')
        res.json({});
    }, function(err) {
              console.log(' error go in')
        next(err);
    });
}`

Comment: client is on app.example.com, api is on api.example.com. Also this problem doesn't appear when I use dev environment. In dev environment I send request directly to API without Apache as proxy server.

Comment: 2) pm2 input in this case:
`POST /cart/5739c9fbc19a8b66c2163ebe/order 200 5003ms
go in
go in
POST /cart/5739c9fbc19a8b66c2163ebe/order 200 30586ms - 1023b`

Comment: Could you show me your  orderModel.createOrder code and apache config

Comment: Create order code: https://paste.ofcode.org/HFgtSrAmjAswXjA5LWVZvs

Comment: apache config for virtual hosts: https://paste.ofcode.org/DCYvhEDdvEW5h2xmSEa7vE
and global apache config: 
https://paste.ofcode.org/qGvVJkgtNifJfkM2MszqQY

Comment: mm.,, everything seem fine. let check again 
1) You said  In Chrome/Firefox dev tools, there is only one request it mean you only receive response one time. Right ?  

2) In this api could you debug the request header, check where is it from 
 
3) Let try reduce your `createOrder ` code, remove some part of your code, divide it to small function and call each one by one?

Comment: Yes in browser dev tools there is only one request, I receive only response. I do small test without calling createOrder, but problem still appear.
https://paste.ofcode.org/vWJ7gswwUmBhfwdxwQxJhL

Comment: 2) In this api could you debug the request header, check where was it called